# Springboot Actuator with Consul

Tags: spring-boot, consul, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-configuration

In Consul, the health status configured in SpringBoot applications can be viewed.

Can anyone know let me know what other metrics (Other than health) can be seen in Consul through Actuator ?

Or can we make Consul to pull/invoke any services/URLs of a services so that the response could be viewed in consul ?

Answer (score 1):

Consul is using health endpoints to determine whether service instance is healthy. If you want custom health status which considers some custom metrics you should implement HealthIndicator interface.

You can expose more information in health api by setting `management.security.enabled=false` in application.properties

In this case you'll see something like this in consul admin UI for your service

```
HTTP GET http://192.168.0.102:8080/health: 200  Output: {"description":"Composite Discovery Client","status":"UP","discoveryComposite":{"description":"Composite Discovery Client","status":"UP","discoveryClient":{"description":"Composite Discovery Client","status":"UP","services":["application","consul"]}},"diskSpace":{"status":"UP","total":499963170816,"free":341478899712,"threshold":10485760},"consul":{"status":"UP","leader":"127.0.0.1:8300","services":{"application":[],"consul":[]}},"hystrix":{"status":"UP"}}
```

You can configure health URL to different endpoint. For instance if you specify `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.healthCheckPath=/health2` then your spring-boot instance will register with the following json (see log snippet below):

```
Registering service with consul: NewService{id='application', name='application', tags=[], address='192.168.0.102', port=8080, enableTagOverride=null, check=Check{script='null', interval='10s', ttl='null', http='http://192.168.0.102:8080/health2', tcp='null', timeout='null', deregisterCriticalServiceAfter='null', tlsSkipVerify=null, status='null'}, checks=null}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. However, I am looking for anyother information other than health.

Comment: you need to look into /metrics endpoint. You can look for the examples here: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators